# Why does this ribbon cable have slots periodically cut between the conductors?

Tags: cables

[image]

It is from an old LED display board.

Comment: A convenient place to install **insulation-displacement** connector.

Comment: Do the cables have connectors? Did you check if connectors are mounted on a slot area or non-slot area?

Comment: Also a convenient place to make solder connections to a PCB.

Answer (score 5):

As @glen_geek and @JustMe instantly pointed out, these slots are there to make it easy to attach a connector...

[image]